# How to replace Qwerty with Dvorak in Fedora 37 / Gnome 3?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, dvorak

I want to use Dvorak as my main layout on my system, but when I set it up via Gnome 3 settings and removed Qwerty I was still able to use it along with Dvorak.

**Added** I’ll start from the beginning, I can’t use the Win + space combination to switch, so I installed Tweaks and already put Ctrl + Shift there and with this method of switching (generally I have 2 layouts, not counting the “qwerty” itself) layouts I got "qwerty" although I deleted it in the settings, which is very disturbing, at the moment I refused it, but I think not for a long time, because there is a need to use any other combinations. Also in my log in screen, I cant use Dvorak, Qwerty only.

How I can completely remove Qwerty and replace it with Dvorak in Fedora 37 with Gnome 3?

Comment: Can you share exactly what you did, what you expected to result, and what the actual result is?

Comment: To expand @mattdm's comment - screenshots could be helpful.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I new here)) where is the best place to attach screenshots?

Comment: @mattdm, I’ll start from the beginning, I can’t use the Win + space combination to switch, so I installed Tweaks and already put Ctrl + Shift there and with this method of switching (generally I have 2 layouts, not counting the “qwerty” itself) layouts I got "qwerty" although I deleted it in the settings, which is very disturbing, at the moment I refused it, but I think not for a long time, because there is a need to use any other combinations

Comment: Please add clarifications to the text in the question, not in comments. Screenshots may be attached using the tool bar that you see when editing your text. Do not add screenshots of text unless it's the visual representation of the text that is the issue.

Comment: You won't be able to add screenshots directly to the question, only links to for example imgur. Don't worry about that, one of us will make them available :-)